# etcd becomes unhealthy after I delete one of master node, I am look for a fix

Tags: kubernetes

I have a Kubernetes clusters setup with kubeadm, 3 master nodes.
One day, one of the master nodes need to be decommissioned (Infrastructure migration), so I deleted that master node by running 'kubectl delete node ***'.
Until a few days ago, I installed a new VM and tried joining it back to the cluster as a master, it failed when checking etcd health state.

```
[check-etcd] Checking that the etcd cluster is healthy
error execution phase check-etcd: error syncing endpoints with etc: dial tcp 10.233.42.22:2379: connect: no route to host
```

Then I go checking the logs of rest etcd pod, looks like it starts to report etcd unhealthy since the master node got deleted.

```
rafthttp: health check for peer 55ab807fd1dc1d4 could not connect: dial tcp 10.233.42.22:2380: i/o timeout

kubectl logs etcd-ne1-prd-lnxstgivt01.ubisoft.org -n kube-system | grep 'could not connect: dial tcp 10.233.42.22:2380: i/o timeout' | awk '{ print $1 }' | uniq
2019-08-12
2019-08-13
2019-08-14
2019-08-15
2019-08-16
2019-08-17
2019-08-18
2019-08-19
2019-08-20
2019-08-21
2019-08-22
```

You can see from the above, the error continuously being reported for days.
I think this might because etcd still remember the node that already deleted. If so, I would like to permanently delete that node also in etcd to avoid the unhealthy state.

Not sure if you ever run into this issue and got a solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I fingured out a resolution.

First, you need to attch into any of etcd pod to remove the deleted master node which still remain at etcd cluster, and make sure cluster is finally healthy.

```
**List current nodes to get failed node id**
/ # etcdctl --endpoint=https://10.0.1.31:2379 --ca-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/ca.crt --cert-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/peer.crt --key-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/peer.key member list
55ab807fd1dc1d4: name=ae1-prd-lnxstgivt01.ubisoft.org peerURLs=https://10.233.42.22:2380 clientURLs=https://10.233.42.22:2379 isLeader=false
3da60ac5e6f29b0e: name=pdc-prd-lnxstginvt01.ubisoft.org peerURLs=https://10.0.1.31:2380 clientURLs=https://10.0.1.31:2379 isLeader=false
d13a6c20fbb32f2d: name=ne1-prd-lnxstgivt01.ubisoft.org peerURLs=https://10.136.66.170:2380 clientURLs=https://10.136.66.170:2379 isLeader=true

**Remove the dead one**
/ # etcdctl --endpoint=https://10.0.1.31:2379 --ca-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/ca.crt --cert-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/peer.crt --key-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/peer.key member remove 55ab807fd1dc1d4
Removed member 55ab807fd1dc1d4 from cluster

**Verify it is removed**
/ # etcdctl --endpoint=https://10.0.1.31:2379 --ca-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/ca.crt --cert-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/peer.crt --key-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/peer.key member list
3da60ac5e6f29b0e: name=pdc-prd-lnxstginvt01.ubisoft.org peerURLs=https://10.0.1.31:2380 clientURLs=https://10.0.1.31:2379 isLeader=false
d13a6c20fbb32f2d: name=ne1-prd-lnxstgivt01.ubisoft.org peerURLs=https://10.136.66.170:2380 clientURLs=https://10.136.66.170:2379 isLeader=true
```

Second, there is a configmap called kubeadm-config in kube-public namespace, it still remember the deleted master node as one of the api end point. This is will block you joining a new master node at stage of checking etcd cluster health state, because kubeadm will read that configmap and take the deleted one as an etcd node to be checked. So export that namespace to yaml file, edit the file and apply it back to delete it from api end points list.

```
kubectl get configmap kubeadm-config -n kube-system -o yaml
apiVersion: v1
data:
  …
  ClusterStatus: |
    apiEndpoints:
      ae1-prd-lnxstgivt01.ubisoft.org:
        advertiseAddress: 10.233.42.22
        bindPort: 6443
      ne1-prd-lnxstgivt01.ubisoft.org:
        advertiseAddress: 10.136.66.170
        bindPort: 6443
      pdc-prd-lnxstginvt01.ubisoft.org:
        advertiseAddress: 10.0.1.31
        bindPort: 6443
    apiVersion: kubeadm.k8s.io/v1beta1
    kind: ClusterStatus
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: …
```

**Tested version**: 1.14.3